# my cat plays only with one toy

Tags: cats

i have a problem as my cat loves particularly one ball.Its strange as he plays with it all the time, one he even swallowed it and then thrown it.I have to hide it quite often and when I do it he stops eating and for me, he has depression.I hide it because he does not relax when he has it or am  afraid that he will eat it again.Please help me to figure out what it means....thank you.Marta

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that seems worrisome is that it happened once that your cat swallowed the ball. All other aspects of your question should not worry you at all.

I have three cats and everyone of them has different favorites toys and ways of playing with them. And also their likes change during time.

I understand your worries about eating the ball again but you definitely should not hide toys because cat "is not relaxed". In fact it is just opposite. Cats love to play and you should provide them with as much occasions to play as possible.

If you are still not comfortable with my answer and the situation in general I would recommend to actively play with the cat as author of "The Cat From Hell" often recommends. This way you could test different toys and different ways to play with them.
Sometimes I try this method with my cats - note that toys can be hard or soft, furry or plain, heavy or light and so on, so on. You can throw the toy in different directions, shake the toy, or even put it on the cat :) Maybe different kind of ball or the same kind but little larger would be good for your cat.

Another very important aspect are social interactions.

Despite of widely used stereotype that cats are solitaries the truth is that they need presence of other beings, especially other cats. So I highly recommend to have two cats (at least ;). You cannot guess in advance what will be relation between them (love, hate or indifference). But even in "indifference" mode it is valuable for cat health to not stay alone for long.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience cats often have have a particular toy or type of toy that is their favorite. Toys that can be swallowed are bad toys and should be removed or used with human supervision only.

I had a cat who loved a silk ribbon. One day she decided to eat it and I found her was running around the house with 5" of ribbon hanging out of her mouth ( the rest in her stomach). I think it was more traumatic to me than her really.

After that she gets no more silk ribbons.

Anyway you should experiment with different toys and find him some safe kitty toys he likes. Playing with your cat with the new toy will probably make the toy more appealing.